# SASS remove unneeded class

Tags: sass

I @import something from bootstrap-sass like

```
@import 'bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/buttons';
```

Then next I extend it to someother name to avoid conflicts when used on an existing web site.

```
.my-cus-btn {
  @extend .btn
}
```

Question now is how can I remove the default .btn in order to avoid messup with existing website/css when used?

Ps: to make it clear, I want the final CSS contains only .my-cus-btn but NO .btn, otherwise this style sheet will mess up legacy code.

But I really want to base on bootstrap-sass or similar framework

Comment: Your current sass code would compile to `.btn, .my-cus-btn {//default properties}`. Now if you want to override default properties, simply add properties to the `.my-cus-btn { }` selector.

Comment: @dsaket yep, but the .btn will still in the CSS, which will conflicts with existing websites' elements with class .btn. I want this new style sheet not affect the existing HTML/CSS

Comment: Try using the `Placeholder` functionality of Sass. It offers something like what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks @dsaket, i think the placeholder is good, but since I am extending an existing library(bootstrap), I don't want to modify the source code in node_modules